# Is a Javascript promise object also a thenable object?

Tags: javascript, promise

I started reading up on Promise for javascript but I am pretty confused with this thenable object. In the guide (https://promisesaplus.com/), it says that anything that has a then method is a thenable. To me, the only thing that is thenable is a Promise. I can't find anything on the web regarding a thenable object so I was hoping I can get some examples here.

Comment: I've never heard of it before. Sounds like a made up term...

Comment: jQuery's deferred is a thenable object, but its not strictly to the Promise A+. [JavaScript Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-lib-compatibility) also gives an example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all they're saying is that if you pass an object which defines 'then' as a method, then they will treat it as if it were a promise.  Whether it's strictly a promise as defined by any standard is not applicable.  This is why you'll hear jquery mentioned as a 'then-able'.

Comment: @aaaaaa Yeah, that makes more sense. The problem now is I can't even test it out because node currently doesn't support Promise yet.

Comment: @YuLinChen: node does support [all these promise implementations](https://promisesaplus.com/implementations). It doesn't matter that it does not have a native `Promise` yet.